# how to use jsonp with jsonify in python and catch the return of the ajax

Tags: python, ajax, flask, jsonp

i want to call a function with ajax using jsonp (as the server i am calling the url is a different one from the one i send the ajax).
The ajax calls a python function that remove some directories and then returns something (the return doesn't matters for me). When it returns, it doesn't return in the success function (it returns on the error function). What i am doing wrong?

P.S: i am using python with jsonify from flask

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://serverPath:1234/deleteDir?path='+ id,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) { console.log(data);},//console.log(data); },
    error: function (data) { console.log(data); },
});
```

PYTHON FUNCTION ON SERVER:

```
@app.route("/deleteDir", methods=['POST', 'GET'])

def deleteDir():
   path =request.args.get('path') 
   pathAdequacao = 'reports/'+path+'/adequacao'
   pathBrain = 'reports/'+path+'/brain'

   try:

      shutil.rmtree(pathAdequacao, ignore_errors=True)
   except:
      pass

   try:
      shutil.rmtree(pathBrain, ignore_errors=True)
   except: 
      pass  

   return jsonify({'response':'ok'})
```

The return that is send to error function (with status 200):

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using JSONP so you have to add the JSONP padding to the result:

```
return '{funcname}({data})'.format(
    funcname=request.args.get('callback'),
    data=jsonify({'response':'ok'}),
)
```

read more about JSONP here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP